# Keep only rows which part of the name is repeated more than 2 times

Tags: r

Lets use `mtcars` as an example. I would like to filter this data and only keep the rows which are "repeated" more than twice (part of the name overlap). In this case from `mtcars` data set I would keep:

`Merc`
'Hornet
`'Toyota`

etc... lets say 5 first characters are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to subtring the first 5 characters of the row names

```
v1 <- substr(row.names(mtcars), 1, 5)
```

Then, get the frequency of the elements and check if it is greater than or equal to 2

```
tbl <- table(v1)>=2
```

Based on this, we subset the dataset

```
mtcars[v1 %in% names(tbl)[tbl], ]
#                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#Merc 280C         17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#Merc 450SE        16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SL        17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SLC       15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#Fiat 128          32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#Toyota Corolla    33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#Toyota Corona     21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#Fiat X1-9         27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Can you additionally tell me how to extract/keep only `TRUE` values from the array called `tbl` ? I would like to have a vector of names.

Comment: @Rechlay Just do `names(tbl)[tbl]` as `tbl` is a logical vector